# How to upgrade my npm version to 8.11.1?

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda

My node version is 8.11.1, but my npm version is 6.0.1. How can I upgrade the npm version to 8.11.1 (same as my node version)?

I had tried `sudo npm install npm -g` and `sudo npm update npm -g`. both not working, what should I do now?

I try to `require('web3')` in `aws lambda`, should I zip all `node_module` and upload to lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6.0.1 is the latest version of npm. npm and Node aren’t versioned in sync.